# Broken front USB port

Tags: usb, repair, case

I have the following case, a [Cooler Master Sileo 500](http://www.coolermaster.co.uk/product.php?category_id=19&product_id=5843)

I had a USB dongle in one of the ports on the front which unfortunately I caught and broke the plastic bit inside. It worked on for a time until the prongs became too bent out of shape, so now it's essentially useless.

Is this fixable? I can't possibly imagine a whole new case is required just to repair the front. I'm *fairly* skilled with a soldering iron so assuming I could get to the PCB could I replace it myself? That's assuming I am able to get the female USB part somewhere.

Comment: If the metal is bent, there is not much you can do, it likely cause physical damage to future USB devices even if you attempted to fix the problem.  Can you not use a differnt port?

Comment: Yes and no. I already have something else in the other front slot (ironically the dongle which caused the break) as it needs line-of-sight, so when I come to plug in a flash drive I have to fiddle around at the back. A last resort would be to string a USB extension round from the back but I thought I'd see if I could do the job properly before I resorted to workarounds.

Comment: A [quick google search](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&q=buy%20type%20a%20usb%20connector&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bGE&fp=839d9582418924f5&biw=902&bih=764&pf=p&pdl=300) shows that you can buy a simple type A USB connecter for as little as £0.42. Thus depending on the inside of the case and its damage (add a picture please) that might be easy to repair.

Comment: @ChrisNicholson - If you have the technical expertise the port itself should be easy enough to replace.  An alternative is a USB 2.0 Hub which might be easier overal, provide you additional slots, since you have 2 ports in front ( one should still work ).

Comment: *"That's assuming I am able to get the female USB part somewhere."* -- That somewhere is an electronics component seller like mouser.com or digikey.com, or maybe Farnell since you're in the UK. You will have to get access to the broken receptacle (or even better, desolder it) to figure out the exact replacement connector that you need to get.

Comment: All very helpful advice. Sorry @Hennes I forgot to take a photo of the thing last night. What I might do first though is see if I can take it apart and get the old port off and then I'll get some photos then which might help identify the exact part I need as well.

Answer (score 2):

Open up your case and look at it.  Typically USB ports are connected to a standard 9-pin header on the motherboard, and replacements are available.  So even though you damaged the front facing connectors, the motherboard should be OK and you can likely just replace the front panel.

In your case, just briefly looking, the front USB ports seem to fit in a standard 3.5" "floppy-drive" size space.  Go to a computer parts site such as tigerdirect.com or newegg.com, and search for something like "3.5 USB front panel" - you'll have a lot of choices.  You might want to get in touch with the manufacturer of your case if you want something that matches it exactly.

Comment: Correct, the motherboard is fine and everything else on the front panel works. I hadn't thought about these things being somehow "standardised" (9 pin, fits in the same size as a 3.5" bay) so it's really interesting to learn I could buy something else entirely to use. I *did* actually find that Cooler Master appears to have a store dedicated to repair parts, so I've found my exact replacement board here http://www.cmstore.eu/cases/others/standard-usb-card-2/. However, I may still look around for something else or have a go at fixing it myself.